# Why can't I use constants in [SuppressMessage(…)] together with ReSharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

I would like to place the strings needed for suppression of ReSharper warnings as constants in a class, so that I do not need to place strings all over and benefit from the find all references function to find out how many times I have suppressed which rule.

```
public class Rules
{
  public const string ReSharper= "ReSharper";
  public const string InconsistentNaming = "InconsistentNaming";
}
```

Decorating my member as follows

```
public class MyClass
{
  [SuppressMessage(Rules.ReSharper, Rules.InconsistentNaming)]
  protected uint v { get; }
}
```

makes ReSharper still complain about properies whose name starts with a lower case letter. Only when attributing the member with

```
[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "InconsistentNaming")]
```

the ReSharper warnings disappear. Is there a way to make it work in the manor stated above using constants?

Comment: Cool idea and could understand you would want that, I don't think its possible because it has to get the value before running (I know its constant:P)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674077/why-cant-i-use-constants-in-suppressmessage-together-with-stylecop sounds similar perhaps?

Comment: @mjwills I asked that question too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper  performs its analysis, and reports warnings, based on the syntax of the source code. So it's looking specifically for string tokens of the form `"ReSharper"`, `"InconsistentNaming"` etc. For it to understand your constants, it would have perform semantic analysis of the code, eg by determining what `Rules.ReSharper` is and then what its value is when it finds it's a string constant.

The latter analysis is much slower and would impact on the performance of ReSharpers analysis. So it doesn't do that and so you have to specify the literal strings.